# Is there any way to debug Sitecore JSS connected mode?

Tags: jss

We have developed Json rendering using existing Sitecore templates and also created JSS components from the JSS application. Somehow in between development facing some issue in code.

As a developer, looking to debug the JSS component in connected mode. Is there any way to debug, please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you want to debug TypeScript/Javascript code:**

When you star `jss start:connected`, you will get message in the console:
`Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/6c4c93c2-ea5e-4022-8ff6-b6fb31c7157f`. It means that there is opened 9229 port, where you can attach using a debugger.

If you use Visual Studio Code, you need *Run and Debug* tool (Ctrl+Shift+D) and attach it to the process. For other IDEs process is the same, you need to attach to the process.

**If you have a custom layout service and want to debug it when JSS app consumes it in connected mode**

In Visual Studio, select Debug > Attach to Process (or press Ctrl+Alt+P). Find *w3wp* process and attach to it.